# Assigning JSON Array to another JSON Array variable

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a JSON Array like this:

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "label":"Red",
         "value":"8"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Yellow",
         "value":"9"
      },
      {  
         "label":"Pink",
         "value":"10"
      }
   ]
]
```

I need to assign this value to new JSON Array variable and should parse the same. Is there any way in Java to accomplish this?

Help is useful!

Comment: I'm working with [simple JSON](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple)

Comment: You have a Json String, that needs to be converted to a JsonArray? Try https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/

Comment: @chaitanya89 can i some code snippet please?

Comment: SO is not a search engine .. but you can easily find thousand of tutorial on how to use JSON in java.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String jsonInString = "[ [ { \"label\":\"Red\", \"value\":\"8\" }, { \"label\":\"Yellow\", \"value\":\"9\" }, { \"label\":\"Pink\", \"value\":\"10\" } ] ]";
        // Convert JSON string to Object
        JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(jsonInString, JsonNode.class);
        if (node.isArray()) {
            // your parsing logic
        }

    }

}
```

Reference: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score -1):

```
org.json.simple.JSONArray yourArray = new org.json.simple.JSONArray();
org.json.JSONArray arr = new org.json.JSONArray(yourArray);
```

Comment: Please add some text describing how your post answers the question. Thank you .